# Android webview inside an Activity not rendering Checkbox / radiobutton

Tags: android, webview

I have a embedded Webview inside my activity, and i am using it like this from code:

```
 private void initialize() {
    app = (HeavenUpApplication) getApplication();
    _webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    listner = new JavascriptListerner(getApplicationContext(), app);
    _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    _webView.addJavascriptInterface(listner, "JSL");
    _webView.getSettings()
            .setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    _webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    _webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    _webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.htm");
    _profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
    _profileImage.setImageBitmap(app.getProfileImage());
}
```

Inside the HTML Page i have some Checkboxes and radio buttons but they refuse to show. only i see is this:

[Image http://theadway.com/capture.png](http://theadway.com/capture.png)!

Option 1/2/3 etc are radio buttons

Comment: Seems like bug in WebView. I encountered this one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by

```
_webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Do you really need that line? The `setLayoutAlgorithm()` method and `WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm` enum are both deprecated so you'd better get rid of the line.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, the reason i added that was to only have vertical scroll.. will do some alternative for the vertical scroll